# How to change div text from load() calls made from included PHP files?

Tags: php, jquery

[image: https://i.imgur.com/38yMTzF.jpg]

`5.php` needs to change text in `index.php` using jQuery. `index.php` includes `2.php`. From `2.php` to `5.php` each PHP is nested into div of that one that's coming before him.

I tried different ways, but always get error that says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

The problem is in `5.php` where jQuery just can't find the `bla` class.

Comment: The jQuery code in 5.php wouldn't cause the error you've stated. If it couldn't find the element, then it simply would do nothing, and fail silently. If you look at the error in your console it should tell you which line threw it. I'd also expect it would tell you exactly what character was the issue

Comment: P.P.S. I'm assuming you've simplified this greatly but the structure does seem a bit mad. Why all the jQuery .load() statements? Why not just use require() on the server side, since you are running .load() the moment the page downloads anyway.

Comment: Thank you for thoughts ADyson, 
For the first part you said about require(), it is made this way because I don't want to load all data to page, but to be loaded when I click on specific button, or svg element etc..
the console points to this 
    `$('#bla').text('blaa');`

Comment: well there's no syntax error on that line, according to what you've written here. So I don't see how that's possible, frankly. (And the error is just a dumb syntax error - JavaScript can't compile your code. It has nothing to do with not being able to find the "bla" element...the code hasn't got as far as actually being executed yet).

Comment: Please make us a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: If we boil it down to just the line of code you're talking about, we can see it definitely doesn't have an error. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vyqh85Lp/ . So work back from there with the rest of your code until you start to encounter problems.

Comment: Okay, Will do minimal code, but should I edit my main post and put it in there?

Comment: yes, if you can't find the issue and still need our help then that's what you need to do, thanks. Often the process of creating the minimal example can help you find the cause yourself anyway.

Comment: oh my god, it was one semicolon :(

Comment: that's the nature of syntax errors, unfortunately. The more you practice, the better you'll get at seeing them straight away. You might benefit from using a code linting tool.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo.

Try to replace `$(.'n2')` and `$(.'n3')` with `$('.n2')` and `$('.n2')`

Comment: Thank you for contribution, but real code is as you said it should be. Not the problem.

Comment: @StevenSagull ... and that's why you should paste snippets of your _real_ code into the question, rather than making pictures out of re-typed code

Answer (score 0):

I had one semicolon error in real code.
It was written like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ducats = <?php echo $PlayerArray[4]; ?>
    $('#ducatelo').text('Ducats: '+ducats);
});
```

And correct should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ducats = <?php echo $PlayerArray[4]; ?>;
    $('#ducatelo').text('Ducats: '+ducats);
});
```